# How to load css in angular 4?

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I can't find a way to import css into my app component. Everything on google shows something else...

In my component i have defind

```
@Component({
   styleUrls : [../css/bootstrap.min.css]
})
```

and everytime i get a Failed to compile message.

This is my file structure:

```
rootFolder/app/appFileIsHere
rootFolder/css/bootstrapFilesAreHere
```

I tried ./css/... but doesn't work css/bootstrap doesn't work ./../css/bootstrap doesn't work. And idk what's left to try, at this point i'm just thinking something's wrong how you define the style path...

Comment: Do you use Angular CLI? You should import boostrap directly into 'global' styles.css that is generated by Angular CLI. Please don't do this in the component.

Comment: How do i do that? @plvice

Comment: Here's a guide: https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/

Comment: thaaaanks @plvice

Answer (score 1):

As plvice suggested you should either, import bootstrap scss file in your global CSS `style.scss`

```
@import 'path/to/css/bootstrap.scss';
```

or declare the min.css in your `.angular-cli.json`

```
...
  "styles": [
    "app/core/preloader/preloader.scss",
    "styles.scss",
    "path/to/css/bootstrap.scss"
  ]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add your CSS file to assets folder and after that, you need to add your CSS file into angular-cli.json(This will apply your CSS to your app and That is in your project folder )

In your(`.angular-cli.json`)

```
"styles": [
        "assets/bootstrap.css"
      ]
```